# Join a GitHub Enterprise

Tags: permissions, github-enterprise, github-organizations

I work for a University and someone invited our group's GitHub organization (we have a free account) to join the University’s GH Enterprise, so we can benefit from the additional features.

I was wondering however, to fully understand pros and cons of this option, does joining the enterprise grant access and admin permissions to anybody - at the enterprise/University level - external to our own GH organization or repos without our/my explicit approval?
Then, if for whatever reason we wanted to leave the enterprise at one point, can we leave it independently or do we need an enterprise admin to “release” our organization?
Also, and more importantly, could this ever end up where an enterprise manager could potentially take full control of our organization's account without our explicit consent?

Online I can only find information on how to [manage organizations](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/admin/managing-accounts-and-repositories/managing-organizations-in-your-enterprise) within your enterprise, or how to [remove yourself](https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-personal-account-on-github/managing-your-membership-in-organizations/removing-yourself-from-an-organization) from an organization. However this is the flipped situation, where (I believe) I would not manage the enterprise account, only one of the organizations within it.